# How to prove a point is not a vertex?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose $S$ is a convex set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. A point $w$ satisfies that $w=\lambda_1 x+\lambda_2 y+\lambda_3 z$, where $\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3=1$, all three coefficients are positive, and $x, y, z \in S$. I want to prove that $w$ is not a vertex of $S$.

I checked the definition of an extreme point, but it involves two rather than three points. So I got stuck. BTW, I am not sure about the definition of vertex, is it the same as extreme point in this case?

Edit: I think I missed one condition: $x$, $y$, and $z$ are not on the same line. Otherwise the proposition I want to prove is not necessarily correct.

Comment: Nit-pick: This is not true if $x$ is a vertex and $x=y=z$.

Comment: hint: assuming all 3 points are distinct, use bunching to write $w = \lambda _1 x + (\lambda_2 + \lambda_3)v$  and figure out $v$